# Trying to open Intellij IDEA lift project generated with gen-idea

Tags: scala, intellij-idea, sbt, lift

I'm trying to get an use the Intellij IDEA for a lift project. I've installed both the sbt and scala plugins and most recently I've followed the instructions here https://github.com/lift/lift_25_sbt. When I open the project, it seems to hang when trying to index the files. It's taking a lot of CPU as well. Not exactly sure where to go from here. I'm using Scala 2.9.2 and Intellij 12. Can someone please help!

Thanks!

Comment: I switched to Intellij 10.5.4 and i'm no longer having issues.

Comment: Try IDEA 12.0.3, if it hangs, the issue should be reported to JetBrains with the logs/[thread dumps](http://www.jetbrains.net/devnet/docs/DOC-260).

Answer (score 3):

JetBrains offers scant support for superceded versions of IDEA (and any plugins). Since 12.0 is the current version, I'd go with that. I can scarcely remember all the shortcomings in the 10.x era, but it has improved steadily since then.

Since IDEA's Scala support is equal in the Community (free, open-source) and Ultimate (commercial) versions, there's little reason not to move up.

Additionally, I don't even know whether the `sbt-idea` plug-in generates project files that can be read by that old a version of IDEA.

**Update**

JetBrains now has EAP (early access program) versions of IDEA 12.1. I'm using it and the latest Scala plug-in EAP releases daily and it works well. Progress continues apace...